# positioning jquery-ui-combify

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using `jquery.ui.combify`.

Following is my `HTML` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqgridcss/jquery.ui.combify.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jqgridjs/jquery.ui.combify.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#MySelect").combify();
            $("#MySelect2").combify();
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <select id="MySelect">
        <option>Some Option</option>
        <option>Some Other Option</option>
    </select>
    <select id="MySelect2">
        <option>Some Option</option>
        <option>Some Other Option</option>
    </select>
</html>
```

I have two `combo-boxes`, which I want to show in a single line, but I am getting this two `combo-boxes` on separate lines.

This is how `combo-boxes` should appear:

[image: select1]

But they are appearing like:

[image]

So let me know if there is a solution for this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code ....

```
<html>
<body>
    <table>
    <tr>
     <td><select id="MySelect">
            <option>Some Option</option>
            <option>Some Other Option</option>
        </select> 
     </td>
    <td>
    <select id="MySelect2">
            <option>Some Option</option>
            <option>Some Other Option</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#MySelect{float:left;}
#MySelect2{float:left;}
```

use `float:left` or `float:right`